# how to change the terminal's theme of vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

My terminal of vscode can't show some words when the color of the words isn't white. So what methods you have to solve the condition,please? For example, change the theme of terminal? But, how to change the theme?

[image: the example of the condition]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the colors of the integrated terminal in the settings.

For example:

```js
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminal.ansiGreen": "#00EE00",
    "terminal.ansiWhite": "#EEEEEE",
},
```

> [Available color settings of integrated terminal.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_integrated-terminal-colors)